# Окончание числительных в истории ревизий

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Собственно [вот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3432/2):

[image: 222]

Comment: Из чата: (Николас) Как я понимаю, проблема с окончаниями числительных все еще имеет место быть, и кроется не в переводе. Попробую найти концы (займет какое–то время).

Comment: Обновил ответ новыми данными.

Comment: @VladD принял ответ с новыми данными.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Была ошибка в transifex ([Tx:5261](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40267317)), исправил.

---

Николас провёл расследование по поводу того, почему обновление строки в Transifex не обновило ответ. Смысл в том, что локализованный текст сообщения фиксируется во время отправки ревизии (поскольку текст мог быть и введён пользователем вручную), так что старый текст больше не будет меняться. Но в новых текстах проблемы быть более не должно.

---

Вот [пример того](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/551573/revisions), что сейчас всё исправилось:

[image: символы]

Comment: Интересно, когда это отразиться на сайте? Вроде как раз в день обещалось пересобираться. Но перевод до сих пор прежний.